# Build tree from flat JSON array in c++

Tags: c++, json

Essentially I have a JSON structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "foo",
        "parent_id": null,
        "value": "This is a root node"
    },
    {
        "id": "bar",
        "parent_id": "foo",
        "value": "This is 2nd level node"
    },
    {
        "id": "baz",
        "parent_id": "bar",
        "value": "This is a 3rd level node"
    },
    {
        "id": "moo",
        "parent_id": "foo",
        "value": "This is another 2nd level node"
    },
    {
        "id": "woo",
        "parent_id": null,
        "value": "This is another root node"
    }
]
```

(Note that there's no ordering going on).

Now I would like to take that and parse it into a tree structure. Something like this (except using C++ types, not JSON):

```
[
    {
        "id": "foo",
        "value": "This is a root node",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "bar",
                "value": "This is 2nd level node",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "baz",
                        "value": "This is a 3rd level node",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "moo",
                "value": "This is 2nd level node"
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "woo",
        "value": "This is another root node"
        "children": []
    }
]
```

I would imagine that it would look something like this, in pseudo-code, but I don't know enough C++ to actually make it work (I'm in the middle of a hack week. I have no idea what I'm doing :) )

```
struct NodeValue {
    std::string id;
    std::string value;
    std::string parent_id;
}

struct Node {
    NodeValue value;
    Node parent;
    std::deque<Node> children;
}

std::deque<Node> buildTree(json::Value nodes) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Node> lookup;

    // Populate our lookup map with all the nodes
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++i) {
        lookup.insert(std::make_pair(nodes[i].id, Node {
            NodeValue {
               nodes[i]["id"].asString(),
               nodes[i]["value"].asString(),
               nodes[i]["parent_id"].asString()
            },
            nodes[i]["id"].asString()
        }));
    }

    // Populate children
    for (lookup::iterator i = lookup.begin(); i != lookup.end(); ++i) {
        Node parent;
        try {
            parent = lookup.at(lookup[i].value.parent_id);
            parent.children.emplace_back(lookup[i]);
        } catch (out_of_range &e) {
            continue;
        }
    }

    // Remove all non-root nodes
    it = lookup.begin();
    while ((it = std::find_if(it, lookup.end(), [] (const Node& n) { return n.parent_id != NULL; })) != lookup.end()) {
        lookup.erase(it++);
    }

    return lookup;
}
```

I don't think this solution would work, unless the nodes are pre-sorted according to their depth level? Also, I literally wrote my first line of C++ two days ago, so have mercy.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Just quick comment: In C++ there is a special type to point to an object - the pointer type - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer. E.g. `Node* parent;` instead of `Node parent;` - `*` matters.

Comment: That code is not C++, it's very close but there's one tiny little thing that makes it not C++: The nested function `isNotRoot`. Nested functions doesn't exist in C++, though some compilers have it as an extension. You should replace it with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: As for your problem, the most common way to construct a tree is through recursion.

Comment: Unless you really want to code it by hand have you considered using a library like JSON++ (https://bitbucket.org/tunnuz/json). There are lots of libraries to choose from BTW.

Comment: @Dennis Will that library (or others) have functions to automatically convert a "flat" JSON to a "nested" JSON like the OP wants?

Comment: I am using a library for parsing the actual JSON. The issue is turning that flat structure into a nested structure.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg (& Tommy): It appears I have completely failed to read the question! Sorry about that. Haven't had my morning coffee yet.

Comment: That's alright @Dennis. Thank you for your contribution anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me out and simplified it greatly:

```
struct NodeValue {
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    std::string parent_id;
};

struct Node {
    NodeValue value;
    Node* parent;
    std::deque<Node> children;
    void populateChildren(std::deque<Node>& source) {
        for (Node &child : source) {
            if (child.value.parent_id != value.id) {
                continue;
            }

            children.push_back(child);
            Node &copy = *(--children.end());
            copy.populateChildren(source);
            copy.parent = this;
        }
    }
};
```

This should reduce the amount of copying and although the source list is perhaps needlessly iterated through, it's definitely fast enough if the dataset is small~ish.

Answer (score 1):

Use a method on the `Node` struct along with a special "root node" collector:

```
struct Node {
    NodeValue value;
    Node* parent;
    std::deque<Node> children;
    void populateChildren(std::deque<Node>& source) {
        while (source.size() > 0) {
            std::deque<Node>::iterator child = std::find_if(
                source.begin(), source.end(), [this](Node possibleChild) {
                    return possibleChild.value.parent_id == this->value.id;
                }
            );
            if (source.end() == child) {
                return;
            }
            child->populateChildren(source);
            child->parent = this;
            children.push_back(*child);
            source.erase(child);
        }
    }
};
```

Then your rootNode has an id of `null`. It's children are then the top-level nodes whose `parent_id` will match `null`.

Then just do:

```
rootNode.populateChildren(setOfAllNodes);
```

I think that should work but I haven't tested it.

EDIT:
Got it :). Below is a full working example (on GCC). The basic idea is the same as above but I had to switch to pointers because obviously I was deleting the underlying object with `erase`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

struct NodeValue{
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    std::string parent_id;
};

struct Node {
    NodeValue value;
    Node* parent;
    std::deque<Node*> children;
    void populateChildren( std::deque<Node*>& source ) {
        auto child = std::find_if( source.begin(), source.end(), [this](const Node* const node){
            return node->value.parent_id == this->value.id;} );
        while ( child != source.end() ){
            (*child)->populateChildren( source );
            (*child)->parent = this;
            children.push_back( *child );
            source.erase( child );
            child = std::find_if( source.begin(), source.end(), [this](const Node* node){
                return node->value.parent_id == this->value.id;
            } );
        }
    }
};


void printChildCount( const Node* node ){
    std::cout << "Node " << node->value.name << " has parent "
            << ( ( node->parent == NULL ) ? "null" : node->parent->value.name ) << " and children: "
            << getListString(node->children) << std::endl;
    std::for_each( node->children.begin(), node->children.end(), printChildCount );
}

int main(){
    std::deque<Node*> nodes;
    Node node1{ NodeValue{ "1", "1", "root" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node2{ NodeValue{ "2", "2", "root" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node3{ NodeValue{ "3", "3", "1" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node4{ NodeValue{ "4", "4", "2" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node5{ NodeValue{ "5", "5", "2" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node6{ NodeValue{ "6", "6", "5" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node7{ NodeValue{ "7", "7", "5" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    Node node8{ NodeValue{ "8", "8", "7" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*>{} };
    nodes.push_back(&node5);
    nodes.push_back(&node6);
    nodes.push_back(&node3);
    nodes.push_back(&node8);
    nodes.push_back(&node4);
    nodes.push_back(&node7);
    nodes.push_back(&node1);
    nodes.push_back(&node2);
    Node rootNode { NodeValue { "root", "root", "" }, NULL, std::deque<Node*> { } };
    rootNode.populateChildren( nodes );
    printChildCount( &rootNode );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out! It isn't quite working, unfortunately. First of all, am I right in assuming that `setOfAllNodes` should be `std::deque<Node>` where each node has been initialized with a `NodeValue` and nothing else? The `NodeValue` will in turn have `id` and `parent_id` set. I've created a gist with my implementation, along with the build errors: https://gist.github.com/Nevon/eb5108b72d8821d1d9b7

Comment: Creating a function local reference to the value and then capturing that reference instead of trying to capture `value` directly seems to have solved the `capture a non-member` issue. I've updated my gist to reflect this. The other issue remains.

Comment: So, I guess that `child` is an iterator which in turn points to a `Node`, so I need to dereference it first: `(*child).populateChildren()`. But somewhere along the line, something goes wrong. Again, I've updated the gist and added another comment (bottom) with the new error.

Comment: `children.push_back(child);` should be `children.emplace_back(*child)`. Now it compiles!

Comment: It seems to be looping infinitely, but it's a start.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the child pointer is being deleted twice, maybe. I'm getting `double free or corruption (!prev)`.

Comment: The above works but not at more than one nesting level I think.

Comment: @TommyBrunn Check out the latest version. I think it should work better than the other proposals. I've tested it with fairly "random" structures and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of this?

```
bool attachToParent(Node* node)
{
    if (node->parent_id == id)
    {
        children.push_back(node);
        return true;
    }

    for (Node* child : children)
    {
        if (child->attachToParent(node))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
if (!root->attachToParent(node))
{
    root->children.push_back(node);
}
```